# How to put list of unordered elements as features into a random forest model

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

Assume that I have 3000 unique rows of data to train with. For each data point, I have a special attribute called $SomeFeatureList. This is a list of independent features (categorical features) that are not of the same length (from 6 - 10), and it is not ordered.

I can expand the feature into 10 independent columns, but I thought about it and decided against it because this would imply artificial relationship that doesn't exist. If I put certain features into column 5 and others into column 4, this doesn't imply that features in column 5 are a distinct group from column 4. In fact each feature in that list are equal to another.

What do I do in this case that would:

1. Make sure each feature within the list is considered by the model - I can't just aggregate them into one feature because that would be creating a lot of arbitrary categories.
2. Generate no arbitrary correlations by putting them into distinct columns.

Thanks! Regards.

Comment: If each row has its own special attributes / variables then how would you compare them?

Comment: It's not special. Think of it as a column but instead of a single feature it contain 6-10 unique features. That's true for all of the rows.

Comment: But are these features compareable between the rows? Do they represent the same thing?

Comment: Yes they represent the exact same thing. Think of it this way, out of 3000 rows you'll have around 100 different features within this list. More or less like a entry of groups of favorite artists from a survey

Comment: So where is the issue then? Why can't you turn this list into a matrix of dimensions 3000 and 101 and use your RF model as you normally would?

Comment: Thanks. That's a valid answer - but what if I have  more and I don't want my dimension to blow up?

Comment: Then you will have to decide how you are going deal with this. Possible options: feature selection and dimensionality reduction.